# How to save shared files by Google Drive links in my account

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing

For example someone emails you a link to a shared PDF on Google Drive.

Is there a way to add it in your Google Drive instead of downloading and uploading it manually?

Also it would be great if the owner decides to delete/revoke access I would still be able to use it.

Answer (score 5):

1. Click 'Shared with Me' on the left side of the Google Drive web interface
2. Right click the file/folder you would like to keep.

After this there are two options:

1. Click 'Make a copy', which will locate a copy in your 'My Drive' folder, but that copy *will not* be synced with anyone else but will be yours even if it is deleted by others

   *OR*
2. Click 'Add to My Drive' which will save a copy to your My Drive folder that *will* be synced but will also disappear if the owner or another editor removes it.

Of course, you could always do both.

Comment: Not working for folders.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the text of the link and in replace “/?...” at the end of the link with “copy”. This goes straight to the  save a copy option

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is this

1. right click on the shared file out of your drive and choose add to my drive
2. go to your google drive account page
3. once more right click on the new link and choose (make a copy)

Then the shared file now is your own and if the person who share file delete it 
you still have your own copy.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use [this extension](https://drive.googleblog.com/2012/12/introducing-save-to-drive-extension.html) on Google Chrome.